# Alternative content directive - Scope issues

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a directive to offer alternative content for different devices, based on a single markup to avoid duplicating code, e.g. make a list of content appear as tabs on large screens or as accordions on small screens.

```
<collection>
  <item>A</item>
</collection>
```

into

```
<main-version>
   <m-ver-item>A</m-ver-item>
</main-version>
<alternative-version>
  <alt-ver-item>A</alt-ver-item>
</alternative-version>
```

I made a plunker with what I have so far, that is currently failing trying to use ng-repeat for example.

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/1IgG2YCn1b8j3HyeMiKy?p=preview

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p65se0cp/

Greetings

Comment: can't check out the code. http://plnkr.co/ is down here :(

Comment: I just added an jsfiddle. (badly organized)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this work instead?

```
angular.module("main", ["ui.bootstrap"])
.controller("MyController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.notes = [{Content: "Lorem Ipsum"},{Content: "Sit amet"}];
    $scope.func=function() { alert("function executed")};
    $scope.title="Title";
}])
.directive("tabGroupResponsive", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        template: function (element, attr) {

            children = element.children();
            var html = "";

            html += "<div>";

            html += "<div class=\"visible-xs\">";
            html += "<accordion>";
            for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                var child = children[i];

                html += "<accordion-group heading=\"" + child.getAttribute("heading") +"\">";
                html += child.innerHTML;
                html += "</accordion-group>";

            }
            html += "</accordion>";
            html += "</div>";

            html += "<div class=\"hidden-xs\">";
            html += "<tabset>";
            for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                var child = children[i];

                html +=  "<tab heading=\"" + child.getAttribute("heading") +"\">";
                html += child.innerHTML;
                html += "</tab>";
            }
            html += "</tabset>";
            html += "</div>";

            html += "</div>";


            return html;
        }
    }
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/DHTcQD12DvBqP1hhVotb?p=preview

I'm not that experienced with this so I'm sure that there may be some downsides to doing it with 'template' just like this, but the end result appears to be good enough, wouldn't you say?

;)

Comment: That really works, I had put this on standby for the moment, after several different approaches. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/3u3h64fw/1/

I used transclusion and added a `tab-group-responsive-item` directive to replace `item`:

HTML:

```
<tab-group-responsive>
    <tab-group-responsive-item heading="Notes33">
        <div>
            <h2 ng-bind="title"></h2>
            <span ng-repeat="note1 in notes">
                <b>{{note1.Content}}</b><br/>
            </span>
        </div>
    </tab-group-responsive-item>
    <tab-group-responsive-item heading="wep"><a ng-click="func()">call func</a></tab-group-responsive-item>
</tab-group-responsive>
```

JS:

```
angular.module("test",[])
.controller("MyController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.notes = [{Content: "Lorem Ipsum"},{Content: "Sit amet"}];
    $scope.func=function() {
        $scope.notes.push({Content: "Added by func"});
    };
    $scope.title="Title";
}])
.directive("tabGroupResponsive", function () {
    return directive = {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: true,
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: '/customTemplate/tabset-responsive.html'
    }
})
.directive("tabGroupResponsiveItem", function ($animate) {
    return directive = {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: true,
        transclude: true,
        link: function ($scope, $element, attrs, ctrl, $transclude) {
            $transclude(function(clone, scope) {
                var elt;
                if ($element.parent()[0].tagName.toLowerCase() === 'accordion') {
                    elt = angular.element("<accordion-group heading=" + attrs.heading + "></accordion-group>");
                } else if ($element.parent()[0].tagName.toLowerCase() === 'tabset') {
                    elt = angular.element("<tab heading=" + attrs.heading + "></tab>");
                }
                elt.append(clone);
                $animate.enter(elt, null, $element);
                $element.remove();
            });
        }
    }
})
.run(["$templateCache", function ($templateCache) {
   $templateCache.put("/customTemplate/tabset-responsive.html",
        "<div><div class=\"visible-xs\">" +
            "<accordion ng-transclude>" +
            "</accordion>" +
        "</div>" +
        "<div class=\"hidden-xs\">" +
            "<tabset ng-transclude>" +
            "</tabset>" +
        "</div>" +
        "</div>");
}]);
```

It should be a good enough start to achieve what you're looking for. There's still room for improvement though.

Comment: Good solution, however it didn't work for me, the outer directive that makes the first transclude gets empty, never triggering the inner item directive, i don't know the reason

Comment: @MatiasMolina: Did you take a look at my jsfiddle? Can you had whatever makes it not work for you ?

Comment: Yes, I saw it working.
I end up with:

`<tab-group class="ng-scope">
     <div><div class="visible-xs">
              <accordion ng-transclude=""></accordion>
            </div>
             <div class="hidden-xs">
                 <div ng-transclude="" class="ng-isolate-scope"></div>
            </div>
</div></tab-group>`

Where the content that is supposed to be appended to the outer directive is empty.

Comment: Can you please update the jsfiddle so that I can see what's not working?

Comment: It I'm not sure what the problem is, but it stop working when the ui.boostrap module is loaded => http://jsfiddle.net/3u3h64fw/2/

Comment: Ok, got it. I'll write another answer related to bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Here's another version of my answer, so it works with bootstrap.

Bootstrap defines a `tabset` transcluded directive, which is why my previous answer was not working.

Same thing apply to `accordion`.

http://jsfiddle.net/3u3h64fw/5/

HTML:

```
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        <tab-group>
            <tab-group-item heading="Notes33">
                <div>
                    <h2 ng-bind="title"></h2>
                    <span ng-repeat="note1 in notes">
                        <b>{{note1.Content}}</b><br/>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </tab-group-item>
            <tab-group-item heading="wep"><a ng-click="func()">call func</a></tab-group-item>
        </tab-group>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
   angular.module("test",["ui.bootstrap"])
    .controller("MyController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
        $scope.notes = [{Content: "Lorem Ipsum"},{Content: "Sit amet"}];
        $scope.func=function() {
            $scope.notes.push({Content: "Added by func"});
        };
        $scope.title="Title";
    }])
    .directive("tabGroup", function () {
        return directive = {
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: true,
            transclude: true,
            templateUrl: '/customTemplate/tabset-responsive.html'
        }
    })
    .directive("tabGroupItem", function ($animate) {
        return directive = {
            require: ['^^?tabset', '^^?accordion'],
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: true,
            transclude: true,
            link: function ($scope, $element, attrs, ctrl, $transclude) {
                var tabsetCtrl = ctrl[0],
                    accordionCtrl = ctrl[1]
                ;
                $transclude(function(clone, scope) {
                    var elt;
                    if (accordionCtrl) {
                        elt = angular.element("<accordion-group heading=" + attrs.heading + "></accordion-group>");
                    } else if (tabsetCtrl) {
                        elt = angular.element("<tab heading=" + attrs.heading + "></tab>");
                    }
                    if (!elt) {
                        return ;
                    }
                    elt.append(clone);
                    $animate.enter(elt, null, $element);
                    $element.remove();
                });
            }
        }
    })
    .run(["$templateCache", function ($templateCache) {
       $templateCache.put("/customTemplate/tabset-responsive.html",
            "<div><div class=\"visible-xs\">" +
                "<accordion><div ng-transclude></div>" +
                "</accordion>" +
            "</div>" +
            "<div class=\"hidden-xs\">" +
                "<tabset><div ng-transclude></div>" +
                "</tabset>" +
            "</div>" +
            "</div>");
    }]);
```

The changes are:

- the `ng-include` attributes in the template are now in an inner div (since `tabset` has to transclude its content)
- the `tabGroupItem` requires an optional parent `tabset` controller to detect if its parent is a `tabset`.

Same thing apply to `accordion`.

Comment: did you mean ng-transclude in the changeset?
tabset, tab, accordion and accordion-group are [ui.bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) directives, maybe the content in the Item needs to be compiled before it gets included in the document, still for some reason, tabset get processed and accordion doesn't